# Correct use of has_many_through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models: `Orders` and `Items`. This is a many to many relationship, but I'm unsure if HMT is correct

```
Order model:
-user_id
-transaction_cost
-delivery_time

Item model:
-price
-name
```

Orders should be able to get all items in the order
Items do not need to be able to get all orders

Comment: [This is basic thing described in guides.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov yes, I checked the guides but was unclear if HMT was correct over HABTM

Comment: HMT is almost always a correct choice unless you are 100% sure you won't ever need intermediate model

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov thanks I'll stick with HMT - but following the patient doctor example, what would you call the intermediate model between orders and items?

Comment: For example you can keep track of item feature in intermediate table, let's say you have item phone which could be colored space gray or white. And this is not only about keeping data in it, it would be much more convenient for you in development.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov ok should I call the model Order_Details?

Comment: Usually you would call it `OrderItem`, because each row references to an order and an item entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention on this is to use the names of both models. A good name might be `ItemOrders`. Has many through is almost certainly a correct choice here.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_orders, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :item_orders
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_orders, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :orders, through: :item_orders
end

class ItemOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Now you just have another `ActiveRecord` model, and you can add to it as you'd like. It will also be helpful for debugging. You can even use a model/scaffold generator to generate these:

```
rails g model item_order order:references item:references
```

This way you get the migrations correct right away. Nothing needs to be altered on your other models except for the above code.